# How to show yAxis value for multiple line

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using echart for display line chart.
In this chart yAxis values are not ploting for red line.
As you can see in tooltip value of green line is match position. At this point red line must be blow 9000.
How can i set yAxis value for multiple line.

[image]

Hare is my echart code

```
<ReactEcharts
                    option={{
                    animationDuration: 1000,
                    tooltip: {
                        trigger: 'axis',
                        axisPointer: {
                        type: 'cross',
                        label: {
                            backgroundColor: '#6a7985'
                        }
                        }
                    },
                    toolbox: {
                        feature: {
                          saveAsImage: {}
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        left: '3%',
                        right: '4%',
                        bottom: '3%',
                        containLabel: true
                    },
                        xAxis: [
                            {
                            type: 'category',
                            boundaryGap: false,
                            data: usersData.indexes
                            }
                        ],
                        yAxis: [
                            {
                            type: 'value',
                            }
                        ],
                        series: [
                            {
                            name: 'Total new users',
                            type: 'line',
                            stack: 'Total',
                            data: [
             5230,4963,5167,5715,5468,4752,9732,9312,8814,7900,6964,6889,7613,9363,5911],
                            smooth: false,
                            showSymbol: true,
                            },
                            {
                            name: 'India new Users',
                            type: 'line',
                            stack: 'Total',
                            data: [2515,2424,2691,2817,2687,2207,6769,4182,3941,3487,2716,2690,3381,4431,1493],
                            smooth: false,
                             showSymbol: true,
                            }       
                        ]
                    }}
                />
```

Comment: I got the solution of this...I removed stack:'Total' from every object of series array.